# Twig tag or function inside PHP String

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is there any way to use something like this?

`$foo = "{{ object|filter }}";`

Because I'm trying to write a dynamic image converter that needs to output something like the example, but when in my twig I use `{{ foo }}`, it just outputs a raw string `{{ object|filter }}` instead of executhing the filter on the object as intended.

I've tried to use `{{ foo | raw }}` but same result.

What I'm trying to do exactly

**CONTROLLER**

```
$image = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemo:Media')->find($id);
$image_src = sprintf("{{ %s | imagine_filter('%s') }}", $image->getWebPath(), 'front_small');
return $this->render('image.html.twig', array(
    'image_src' => $image_src
));
```

**TWIG**

```
<img src="{{ image_src }}"/>
```

So, I have a twig function inside a PHP variable `$image_src`, that Twig function could be, once formatted with `sprintf` `{{ '/uploads/foo.jpg' | imagine_filter('front_small') }}`.

That is a string for now, because it's inside a php variable `$image_src`, that variable is sent to my Twig template with the name `image_src` so, for now it is a string as I've said, if I do

`My variable contains "{{ image_src }}"` It will output a **string** that says:

`My variable contains "{{ '/uploads/foo.jpg' | imagine_filter('front_small') }}"`

Because, as I've said, `image_src` is just a string, but I want to acutally execute inside my Twig, the string that contains `image_src`, because yes, it is a string (to the eyes of the compiler) but we all know it is or it is pretended to be a Twig function (because of the syntax).

So, why `| raw` **will not** work?, because it is inteded to be used with strings containing `HTML` code, if it were `HTML` syntax it would work, but it's a `Twig` syntax, so It doesn't work.

Resuming, there should be a `| compile` twig function that executes Twig code inside a variable like `| raw` does with HTML, but, as this function doesn't exists, I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve it...

As @joshua said, it's like a Javascript `eval`.

I hope I've explained good what is the problem and what I need.

**EDIT**

I've used my own twig extension `Compile` in order to achieve what I needed.

```
class CompileExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'compile'   => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'compile', array(
                'needs_environment' => true,
                'needs_context'     => true,
                'is_safe'   => array('compile' => true)
            )),
        );
    }

    public function compile(\Twig_Environment $environment, $context, $string)
    {
        $loader = $environment->getLoader();

        $compiled = $this->compileString($environment, $context, $string);

        $environment->setLoader($loader);
        return $compiled;
    }

    public function compileString(\Twig_Environment $environment, $context, $string)
    {
        $environment->setLoader(new \Twig_Loader_String());
        return $environment->render($string, $context);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'compile';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Accepting @Benjamin Paap answer because it does exactly what I wanted in this case with better code, but my custom Twig class works for every situation.

Comment: Are you trying to use a twig filter in PHP or want html output from your custom filter?  Any code?

Comment: you should read this, and `{{ foo|raw }}` should work : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Comment: you want something like javascript's `eval`, don't you? I don't think that the twig guys put a feature that possibly dangerous as `eval` into their project.

Comment: JCSama As I've said, {{ foo|raw }} doesn't work neither.

@Rooneyl I'm trying to use a twig filter inside twig but using the string from PHP. I've updated my code with an example.

Comment: Yeah @Joshua that's exactly what I want, kind of.

Comment: would this be kind of what you are asking for? https://github.com/marcj/twig-apply_filter-bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible in twig without a TwigExtension which renders your string separately.

But looking at your code you're trying to use the LiipImagineBundle the wrong way. It seems tempting to use it this way, but the correct way to generate a url for your thumbnails would be this:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // RedirectResponse object
        $imagemanagerResponse = $this->container
            ->get('liip_imagine.controller')
            ->filterAction(
                $this->request,         // http request
                'uploads/foo.jpg',      // original image you want to apply a filter to
                'my_thumb'              // filter defined in config.yml
            );

        // string to put directly in the "src" of the tag <img>
        $cacheManager = $this->container->get('liip_imagine.cache.manager');
            $srcPath = $cacheManager->getBrowserPath('uploads/foo.jpg', 'my_thumb');

        // ..
    }
}
```

https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle#using-the-controller-as-a-service

Comment: I think your method is better than the one I've made (I've made a twig extension in order to compile functions using Twig_Loader_String, so I will try it :)

Comment: Working like a charm! :) Thank you!